# Add Timeout to task

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am calling a web service that will return data that I intend to put into a SQLite database for the mobile app.  The problem is that the service takes some time to return the data and the app performs a timeout and fails.

How can I incorporate a task within my HelperFile to be sure it returns successfully to the calling function?

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await ProcessData();
        });

    }

    private async Task ProcessData()
    {

        HelperFile myHelper = new HelperFile();

        //Pass Information to Webservice
        Uri jsonUrl1 = new Uri(string.Format("https://www.myURL.com/page.asmx/GetMyData"));


        var result = await myHelper.GetResponseString(jsonUrl1);
        //JObject rss = JObject.Parse(result);

       jsonCredit_Union.RootObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<jsonCredit_Union.RootObject>(result);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, jsonCredit_Union.JobCode> kvp in obj.Results.JobCodes)
        {
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DB_PATH))
            {
                tblCredit_Union tcu = new tblCredit_Union()
                {
                    cuName = kvp.Value.cuName,
                    cuPhone = kvp.Value.cuPhone,
                    address1 = kvp.Value.address1,
                    city = kvp.Value.city,
                    state_id = kvp.Value.state_id,
                    zip_Code = kvp.Value.zip_Code,
                    longitude = kvp.Value.longitude,
                    latitude = kvp.Value.latitude
                };

                conn.CreateTable<tblcredit_union>();
                conn.Insert(tcu);

            }
        }
    }
```

Here is where it fails and returns "Task was cancelled".  Due to the timeout I am unable to get to the point of checking the ResponseCode.

```
    public class HelperFile
{
    //Returns a json recordset from a provided URL
    public async Task<string> GetResponseString(Uri url)
    {
        try
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
                {
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                        {
                            string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            return myContent;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return "Error";
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: HttpClient has a Timeout property you can set to a custom value

Comment: Thanks I did have the following code:  client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);  I believe I am going to change how it gets the data and pre-load the data for each release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing to think about is that your app, as a client, cannot ensure the server returns your call successfully.  If its taking too long, as mentioned in the comment, you can set the timeout on the HttpClient within your helper class.

Right now, you have a try catch in the helper, but not in the `ProcessData()` call. So- when the task does time out and throws an exception, your app is likely crashing.  You can test this by using a network conditioner or putting the device/simulator in airplane mode.

Another scenario is that you have a call to the server and it returns a non Success Status Code.  Right now, you return a string of `"Error"`- but this return value is not addressed in `ProcessData()`

A starting point might be moving the Try/Catch out of your helper and in to your code behind (xaml.cs file).  Another idea might be to move the serialization into your Helper class....hopefully that helps point you in the right direction.